# Integration test a parent POM

Tags: java, maven, junit, maven-failsafe-plugin

I have a company parent POM that I would like to integration test. The integration test should be building example projects with the company parent POM.

I thought about setting this up with the failsafe Maven plugin and JUnit, but my problem is:

- I do not want any dependencies in the company parent POM
- To run JUnit tests, I need to have JUnit as dependency

Is there any way around this problem?

Comment: Can't you just create a separate test project? You can probably put it in the same repository, as long as you don't include it in the parent POM (e.g. as module). Refer to the parent using `<relativePath>`, then build the test project from its own directory.

Comment: Another idea: in your src/test/resources, add an entire, simple Maven project that uses the parent pom you want to test. Invoke Maven programmatically from your tests to that dummy project (or projects). I believe it should be possible but never done that, so treat this as just an idea.

Comment: Do you test the pom or more accurately the configuration of plugins within that pom file?

Comment: @khmarbaise I want to make sure that changes to the company parent POM don't break the build of the projects using it. So the test should run builds of example projects with the new parent POM to make sure these builds still succeed.

Comment: You could simply make a integration module project which contains only those tests... but will not being published. (skip deployment)... ?

Comment: But I don't want to add modules to my company parent POM. I could either add an additional aggregator POM or build the integration module separately with the CI server, but I am not sure yet.